# GeoServer's monitor extension crashing

Tags: geoserver

We are using GeoServer version 2.7.6 and recently we added monitor extension plugin and our main objective is to have an audit logging mechanism.

For that reason, we install monitor core and hibernate extensions separately. After installing the core, we tested GeoServer and it's working fine but the major problem is, it is creating the log files with 0 KB. So then we added hibernate extension, GeoServer is getting stopped.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Geoserver's hibernate extension is one of most forgotten extensions in project... I'm using it in production and it's randomly working/not working between versions... Now I'm using 2.10.0 and it this version it's working. I've created issue to some older version and after 6 months I got answer that this module has no maintainer, so there is nobody to solve my issue - I'm free to fix it by myself...

Comment: to even consider looking at this we'd need to see the detailed log file output of the crash.

Comment: @Jendrusk - don't forget that you can always buy support for GeoServer if you don't want to step up and become a contributor to a tool that you are using in production.

Comment: @iant - more complex thing... I would help with geoserver with pleasure cause I'm using it and I think it's good soft, but all I know about JAVA is how to spell it... Buying sth is more a case of firm I'm working in, not mine.... the company sees no need - wms is working so all additional is no needed... Most frustrating was, that this was an official release and wasn't working just out-of-the-box... at all. Like someone included it into release and didn't even tried to run it once. I know that's free software, I didn't paid for it, but still I think that released version should be working...

Comment: the only other option is to delete it completely - allowing unsupported modules to be released and used at least allows people to take an interest in them,